# Get all child hierarchy of a parent

Tags: mysql, sql, database, hierarchy, self-join

I have a table **employeehierarchy** in which I have many records. I want to fetch all records in the hierarchy of senior.

In this table Anshul is senior most employees and I want to get all junior employee name which are under Anshul i.e Yogesh, Chirag, Vimal and Ajay.

```
|   Id    |           name           |    | Senior     |    |  |  |  |  |
+---------+--------------------------+----+------------+----+--+--+--+--+
|      14 | Anshul                   |    |          0 |    |  |  |  |  |
|      15 | Yogesh                   |    |         14 |    |  |  |  |  |
|      16 | Chirag                   |    |         15 |    |  |  |  |  |
|      17 | Vimal                    |    |         16 |    |  |  |  |  |
|      18 | Ajay                     |    |         17 |    |  |  |  |  |
```

I need a mysql query for achieving this.
Thanks

Comment: http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/

Comment: MySQL does not support recursive queries. You need to do this in your application or write a stored procedure. See here for more information: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=mysql+hierarchical+query

Answer (score 1):

May this will help someone,

```
    SELECT  @id :=
        (SELECT  Id
        FROM    employeehierarchy
        WHERE   Senior = @id
        ) AS employee
FROM    (
        SELECT  @id := 14
        ) vars
STRAIGHT_JOIN
        employeehierarchy
WHERE   @id IS NOT NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need something in your database to create a relationship between your sr and junior employee. Unfortunately its beyond the scope of this question on how you implement this relationship. As this touches more on database architecture.
 One option is to create a new field in your existing table which holds the id of your senior, for each employee.
  Another option would be to have a separate table where you have three fields id, employee id, senior id.

I suggest the second option. Then you can berform a conditional join in you SQL.